# Use Python to generate input to XeTeX

Tags: math-mode, xetex, python

I am wondering what is a good way to use Python to generate an arithmetic worksheet consisting only of 2-digit numbers squared. Specifically I want to be able to call upon a Python program in which it asks me for parameters such as the range of the numbers in can call upon to square and the number of questions I want to generate. Once that is done the program will generate the numbers and then automatically open up a .tex file (already with preamble and customizations) and basically do a loop for each question like this:

```
\begin{exer}
n^2
\end{exer}
%%%%%Solution%%%%%%

\begin{solution}
n^2=n^2
\end{solution}
```

for some integer n.

Once it is done writing the .tex file then it will run xetex and output the pdf ready to use and print. Any help or suggestions? Python is preferred but not mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your problem is so simple that doesn't require any special magic. However I would suggest you don't try to append your generated content into a file you already have with preamble, good practice is to leave it untouched and include (in fact you can copy it on generation or use TeX \include).

Now, let's add more to the generation. [Python formatter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) is your friend here, you use the example you've given as a template, and write the product into a file in every iteration. Don't forget to escape "{" brackets, as they're symbols used by formatter.

At the end, (suggestion) you can [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to launch XeTeX - depending on your need `call()` is enough or use `popen()`.